# List of structs vs classes

Tags: c#, dictionary, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a relatively small dictionary (a few hundred entries at most) that is receiving many calls (hundreds, possibly thousands per second) and many of them requires entry modification.

Performance wise, which one of this solution is generally recommended for a small list with frequent updates?

1. unboxing-boxing structs
2. define structure methods for each parameter that requires modification
3. use classes, that can be directly modified because they are referenced unlike structures

Comment: What do your experiments show you, and are these *naturally* value types? It's not at all clear why you'd need boxing here... `List<T>` doesn't box values.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from testing this yourself?

Comment: @JonSkeet I probably misunderstood the concept. What I mean is store list value in a temp structure, modify it and put it back in the list.

Comment: @Chris If you are actually using a dictionary or other collection type that requires hashing the item, you need to be careful what you change. If you mutate a value that forms part of the hash, you run the risk of losing the object in the dictionary or returning the wrong object. So in any case, your use case would be to remove the item from the dictionary, modify it, and put it back in - unless you know what you are changing doesn't affect the hash.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I use a dictionary, and the key is not modified, only the value.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko The problem is rather complex, and I wanted some guidance first.

Comment: @Chris Also note that if you are using a generic collection type, then boxing won't be an issue with a value type.

Comment: Well it's hard to give *general* guidance without more specifics... we have no idea what's going to be in the entries, so we can't really tell whether they're naturally value types or reference types. I'd be very reluctant to make that decision based on *just* this requirement.

Comment: @JonSkeet The dictionary is a network routing table and the entries contains the connection status: timestamp, bools, int, socket, protocol type .. so both.

Comment: @Chris: Well that *definitely* doesn't sound like a value type to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really avoid mutable value types (i.e. structures that can be modified) if at all possible, as it basically breaks the concept of a "value type" if one or more attributes of a value are not intrinsically part of the value itself (and thus can't be changed). If you need to store values that can be changed, then you should be using a class.